# Scrapy to dataframe to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scrapy

I have a scrapy code here that outputs a json file. I then imported the json file into a dataframe using jupyter notebook to clean the data. However, what I really want to do is be able to run the scrapy spider and output the data as a CSV already cleaned, instead of me saving the scraped data as a json file and going into jupyter notebook to clean it. Is there anyway to connect the two process? Below is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import json
import datetime
from seatgeek.items import SeatgeekItem

class seatgeekSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "seatgeek_spider"
    #showname = input("Enter Show name (lower case please): ")
    #showname = showname.replace(' ', '-')
    start_urls = ["https://seatgeek.com/come-from-away-tickets?page={}".format(i) for i in range (1,35)]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 3,
        'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'test.json'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="event-listing-title"]/@href').extract():
            item = SeatgeekItem()
            item['performance'] = href.split('/')[-3]
            item["eventId"] = href.split('/')[-1]

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = 'https://seatgeek.com/listings?id=' + item['eventId'] + '&aid=11955&client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4',
                callback=self.parse_ticketinv,
                meta={'item': item})

    def parse_ticketinv(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        item = response.meta['item']
        for i in jsonresponse["listings"]:
            item["sectionName"] = i["s"]
            item["zoneName"] = i["s"].split(' ')[0]
            item["currentPrice"] = i["p"]
            item["listingPrice"] = i["p"]
            item["row"] = i["r"]
            item["seatNumbers"] = ""
            item['listingId'] = i["id"]
            item['quantity'] = i["q"]
            item['vendor'] = "SeatGeek"

            yield item
```

And this is my code for cleaning the data:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

path = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\Code\seatgeek\test.json'

with open(path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[df.performance.str.contains('gerald')]
df['performance'] = df['performance'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('gerald-schoenfeld-theatre-').rstrip('-pm'))
df['performance'] = df['performance'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d-%H'))

df['datePulled'] = pd.to_datetime('today')

filename = input('Enter filename: ')
df.to_csv(filename + '.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

**EDIT:**

Per @stranac's help, I've updated my pipeline with the the code below. However for some reason, I seem to be missing/some rows I do not want are being deleted. It seems like if I comment out `item['performance'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['performance'][26:],'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%p')`, it would works fine.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
   if 'gerald' not in item['performance']:
      raise DropItem
   item['performance'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['performance'][26:],'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%p')
   item['datePulled'] = datetime.datetime.now()
   return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to write your own [item pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), and do the cleanup per item in `process_item()`, instead of doing it all at once using pandas.

```
class YourPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if 'gerald' not in item['performance']:
            raise DropItem
        # do your cleanup
        return item
```

Sidenote:
[lstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) don't do what you think, they just happen to produce the correct result in this case.

EDIT:

The error you get is caused by the same item being yielded multiple times from `parse_ticketinv`.
This causes the already-modified item (`item['performance']` being replaced by a `datetime` object) to pass through the pipeline again, causing a `TypeError`.

The simplest way to solve the problem is creating a new item each loop, or yielding item copies:

```
def parse_ticketinv(self, response):
    # for whatever:
        # do stuff
        yield item.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I seem to get a name error `NameError: name 'DropItem' is not defined` how can I fix this? _(updated code in my original post)_ Also for some reason, I seem to be missing/some rows I do not want are being deleted. It seems like if I comment out `item['performance'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['performance'][26:],'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%p')`, it would works fine, so the problem is with this line, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: `DropItem` needs to be imported (shown in the docs link). As for your missing rows, check the log for errors, but my guess is that the value of `item['performance']` might be different than what you expect.

Comment: I fixed the `DropItem` problem - thank you. Playing around with the pipeline, it seems like if I comment out all of the data cleaning, I have all of the rows I need. However even if I add a line like: `item['performance'] = item['performance'][26:]`, some rows are being deleted and I get no errors in my log.

Comment: I've edited the answer, updating your post with the error (preferably a full traceback) is probably a good idea.

Comment: Ah the updated answer worked! Thank you so much for your help.